# Group by 'Date' while calculating average on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: ID, Date, Data_Value reporting temperature records (Data_Value) day by day in a given period (Date - day by day) from different weather stations (ID). What I need is to 'group by' every single day and calculate the average temperature for each day, e.g.

```
ID      |   Date       | Data_Value
------------------------------------
12345   |   02-05-2017 |  22
12346   |   02-05-2017 |  24
12347   |   02-05-2017 |  20
12348   |   01-05-2017 |  18
12349   |   01-05-2017 |  16
```

becomes:

```
ID      |   Date       | Data_Value
------------------------------------
.....   |   02-05-2017 | 22
.....   |   01-05-2017 | 17
```

Could someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggreagate `mean`:

```
df = df.groupby('Date', as_index=False, sort=False)['Data_Value'].mean()
print (df)
         Date  Data_Value
0  02-05-2017          22
1  01-05-2017          17
```

And then if need also `ID` values use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
df = df.groupby('Date', as_index=False, sort=False)
       .agg({'Data_Value':'mean', 'ID':lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))})
       .reindex_axis(['ID','Date','Data_Value'], axis=1)
print (df)
                  ID        Date  Data_Value
0  12345,12346,12347  02-05-2017          22
1        12348,12349  01-05-2017          17
```

Or if only first value of `ID` aggregate by [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = df.groupby('Date', as_index=False, sort=False) 
       .agg({'Data_Value':'mean', 'ID':'first'}) 
       .reindex_axis(['ID','Date','Data_Value'], axis=1)
print (df)

      ID        Date  Data_Value
0  12345  02-05-2017          22
1  12348  01-05-2017          17
```

Comment: This works perfectly, wasn't that hard...thank you so much!